# Why there is an isomorphism $D(soc^{i}M) \cong DM/rad^{i}DM$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, socle

I am reading the book *Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras*, volume 1, by Assem et al. On page 162, it is written $D(soc^{i}M)\cong DM/rad^{i}DM$, where $DM=\mathrm{Hom}(M,k)$.

We define $soc^{i}M$ inductively as follows: $soc^{0}M=0$ and, if $soc^{i}M$ is already defined and $p:M\rightarrow M/soc^{i}M$ denotes the canonical epimorphism, we set $soc^{i+1}M=p^{-1}(soc(M/soc^{i}M))$. Thus, by definition, $soc^{i+1}M\supset soc^{i}M$. Then we get a socle series: 
$0=soc^{0}M\subset socM \subset soc^{2}M \subset \cdots \subset M$.

I don't know how to prove the identity $D(soc^{i}M)\cong DM/rad^{i}DM$, for any integer $i\geq 0$. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much. In particular, for $i=1$, $D(socM)\cong DM/radDM$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you make your question self-contained -- I think it is not reasonable to assume that people look up a particular book in order to understand your question.

Comment: Somehow, you stop in the middle of defining $soc^{i+1}M$.

Comment: These definitions are standard in representation theory and asking for then is like asking to define the lower central series. But cross posting is not good and this question is better for mse.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I have deleted that question. I will edit this question in a clear way.